# change CSS based on value Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

I want to change label color and cursor type based on ng-model

**index.html**

```
<button ng-click="changeType()">Change</button>
<label class="fee-type" ng-style="feeType ==='one' && {'class':'disabled-class'}" for="fixed2">Client Contengency Fee</label>
<label class="fee-type"  ng-style="feeType ==='one' && {'class':'disabled-class'}" for="fixed1">Fixed Fee Per Property</label>
```

The default class is **fee-type** but when then button get clicked its class should change to **disabled-class**

**index.css**

```
.fee-type {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 1em 0 0;
    color: black;
}

.disabled-class {
    color:gray;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

**index.js**

```
$scope.feeType= two;

$scope.changeType= function(){
    $scope.feeType=one;
}
```

Comment: use ng-class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-class` instead of `ng-style` and add condition in `ng-class` to apply css class in your label.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="changeType()">Change</button>
<label class="fee-type" ng-class="{'disabled-class':feeType ==='one'}" for="fixed2">Client Contengency Fee</label>
<label class="fee-type" ng-class="{'disabled-class':feeType ==='two'}" for="fixed1">Fixed Fee Per Property</label>
```

and controller

```
$scope.feeType = 'two';

$scope.changeType = function() {
   $scope.feeType = 'one';
};
```

Comment: value of  `feeType` should be `string` so use quotation like  `'one'` instead of `one` in your controller